# File keeps showing as modified

Tags: git

I have a very strange problem with one file in git.

- the file Example.php was already present when I created new branch feature/xyz
- I changed the file and committed/pushed to feature/xyz
- feature/xyz was merged back into develop
- when I checkout develop, Example.php shows as modified
- if I try to commit, it says:
  `1 file failed to commit: git fix On branch develop Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'. Changes not staged for commit: Example.php`
- if I revert, the file reverts to the status it had before my push in feature/xyz, but shows as modified directly after
- if I revert again then, it shows what it's like in develop now (which it should) but then turns to modified immediately again

Things I tried:

- changing the file and committing, but it keeps on showing as modified
- git clean
- git stash
- force a checkout on master, delete local develop branch, check out develop again (same result)
- it even happens without IDE, if I stash I see a change immediately after

I'm stuck in an endless loop. How do I break out?

Comment: Are you working in an IDE which has auto-correct capabilities?

Comment: I'm not sure what auto-correct means in this case, but I am using an IDE (PHPStorm) yeah.

Comment: Some IDEs, such as IntelliJ, will do some auto-formatting of source code files.  So, this could be causing a certain file to always be showing up as modified, despite that you never modified it by your own hand.

Comment: Yeah I am using an IntelliJ IDE but never had this happen before. I can just revert and revert and revert forever.

Comment: One quick workaround would be to make sure that this source file is _closed_ completely before doing any Git operations.  AFAIK auto correct/format won't operate on a file not loaded.

Comment: Same result. If I close the file and revert, it shows up as modified directly after.

Comment: Then you may have to disable auto-formatting rules.  Or, just accept that the file is changed, and commit that result.

Comment: I can't commit because it's the same as the remote one. If I make a change and commit it will show up changed directly after.

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  If the file is getting changed and showing up in your change set, then you _can_ commit, right?

Comment: I'd think so but I can't. If I do make I change I can commit but it shows changed directly after. If I try to commit the file the way it is remote then it won't allow me to commit.

Comment: Just remembered something: This could also be caused by IntelliJ auto-formatting the line endings of your file.

Comment: The same thing happens on the cl, without IDE open.

Comment: One possibility could also be Windows/UNIX case sensitivity issues... don't have an example at hand, but sometimes things get messy when you renamed a file on Linux, for example (e.g. `example.php` to `Example.php`) and then update on Windows (or even worse, if you have two files with the same name which only differ in their case).

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. I just found out. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a case issue.

My colleague changed capitals of a folder name.